# How to subtract a median of three observations by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Say, i have dataset.

```
structure(list(SKU = c(13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 
13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L), stuff = c(4565, 
0, 0, 0, 567.0065222, 0, -1, 73.82897425, -1, 567.0065222, 614.2570658
), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), acnumber = c(329L, 
329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L), 
    year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", "stuff", 
"action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

The action column has only two values 0 and 1.
As we can see there is 1 observation by stuff of 1 category and  10 obs by stuff of zero category.

1.I have to calculate the median of three last observations, but  all that less or equal zero in Stuff column is not needed. So  i must work with three last obs. of stuff colums by 0 action's category.

```
567,0065222
73,8289742
567,0065222

the median =567,0065
```

2. Now, i must  take a single value  of 1 action's category and subtract from it the calculated median

   614,2570658-567,0065222=47,2505436

I do that

```
AwesomeData %>% {.[.$stuff>0,]} %>% {.[.$action==0,]} %>% tail(3) %>% {median(.$stuff)} -> OURMEDIANA
AwesomeData %>% {.[.$action==1,]} %>% {.$stuff}-OURMEDIANA -> WHATWENEED
a=cbind(AwesomeData,WHATWENEED)
```

but what if i have two groups
some like that's

```
structure(list(SKU = c(13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 
13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13284L, 13285L, 13285L, 
13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 13285L, 
13285L), stuff = c(4565, 0, 0, 0, 567.00652, 0, -1, 73.82897, 
-1, 567.00652, 614.25707, 4565, 0, 0, 0, 567.00652, 0, -1, 73.82897, 
-1, 567.00652, 614.25707), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
), acnumber = c(329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 
329L, 329L, 329L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 
330L, 330L, 330L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Now we have new group

```
SKU +acnumber+year
13285+330+2017
```

how to use this strings for all groups in dataset

as output i see

```
     SKU    stuff action acnumber  year   new
   <int>    <dbl>  <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 13284  4565         0      329  2018  3998
 2 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 3 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 4 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 5 13284   567         0      329  2018     0
 6 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 7 13284 -   1.00      0      329  2018 - 568
 8 13284    73.8       0      329  2018 - 493
 9 13284 -   1.00      0      329  2018 - 568
10 13284   567         0      329  2018     0
```

but i must see

```
SKU acnumber    year    result  
13284   329 2018    47,25055    
13285   330 2017    47,25055    614,25707-median of three last obs. Of zero (567,00652)
```

Comment: no i must subtract only three last value of zero category

Comment: @akrun i edited post, can you check it

Comment: we delete all that less or equal zero in zero category of action in stuff column, than calculate median with last obs. of zero categories. my strings do this task, but i need by groups

Comment: @akrun i need median of three last observation

Comment: @akrun yes i want summarised one row data

Comment: @akrun good.now substract 614,25707-567in new column "result". 614,25707 it is single obs in stuff by 1 category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by 'SKU', 'acnumber', 'year',  subset the last 3 observations of `stuff` where 'action' is 0 and 'stuff' is positive, take the `median` and substract from the last 'stuff' observation where 'action' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(SKU, acnumber, year) %>% 
  summarise(new = tail(stuff[action ==1], 1) -  
                   median(tail(stuff[action == 0 & stuff > 0], 3)))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   SKU, acnumber [?]
#    SKU acnumber  year   new
#  <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 13284      329  2018  47.3
#2 13285      330  2017  47.3
```

Comment: as output i see      SKU    stuff action acnumber  year   new
   <int>    <dbl>  <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 13284  4565         0      329  2018  3998
 2 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 3 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 4 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 5 13284   567         0      329  2018     0
 6 13284     0         0      329  2018 - 567
 7 13284 -   1.00      0      329  2018 - 568
 8 13284    73.8       0      329  2018 - 493
 9 13284 -   1.00      0      329  2018 - 568
10 13284   567         0      329  2018     0